# c# Оптимизация сортировки линии

Tags: c#, сортировка, оптимизация, filter

Особо нет идей, как это улучшить, потому что для 1000+ элементов уж больно долго работает. Уверен, что есть способ лучше, просто знаний не хватает в этом отношении

```
public bool SortFilterLine(string filter)
{
    return time.Contains(filter) || direction.Contains(filter) || roomCopy.Contains(filter) || userCopy.Contains(filter)
        || objectContainer.Contains(filter) || command.Contains(filter) || data.Contains(filter);
}
```

Comment: Что мы должны понять в вашем коде? Какие то переменные, что то делают. Вы можете с тем же успехом код убрать из вопроса, он не помогает понять вашу проблему.

Comment: Я показываю сортировку фильтра линии, в нём содержатся переменные, среди которых составляется фильтр, как по мне, то тут только от незнания можно не понять код. Переменные типа string, Contains один из методов, можете посмотреть документацию

Comment: что такое линия? Что такое остальные переменные? Метод Contains может принадлежать разным типам. Какая задача у вас? Может вам и не надо вызывать Contains, может вы сможете простейшее индексирование сделать заранее? Много вопросов, мало ответов, потому тут и нечего подсказать.

Comment: это в основном технические вопросы. Contains в данном случае принимал в себя строку filter, так что можно было понять, что это за тип данных. Но я с вами соглашусь, это надо было расписать, так что извиняюсь

Comment: Плохой вопрос, ничего не понятно, не могу вам помочь. Если хотите оптимизировать код, задайте другой вопрос, но так, чтобы вашу проблему можно было воспроизвести на каких-нибудь тестовых сгенерированных данных. С большой вероятностью проблема производительности вообще не в этом куске кода. И что такое линия?

Comment: Единственное, что приходит в голову,это создать еще одно поле и склеить в него все остальные поля единоразово, разделяя каким-нибудь редким символом типа `|` - `string.Join()`. А затем `Contains` гонять по уже склееным строкам, будет всего один вызов на группу.

Comment: `Contains в данном случае принимал в себя строку filter, так что можно было понять, что это за тип данных` Лично я подумал изначально на HashSet. Как я мог понять, что это строка, мне непонятно.

Comment: @aepot можно построить префиксное дерево, куда запихать все строки по которым ищем (используя банально trie). Тогда поиск подстроки длиной M сразу по всех строках займет M операций максимум, то есть ускорение раз в 10 на вскидку. Но я бы не стал такое предлагать не зная контекста задачи.

Comment: Ну и где тут вообще сортировка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще, насколько я помню, Contains работает при помощи суффиксного дерева, то есть работает за О от длинны фильтра - это довольно быстрый алгоритм. Правда, в начале время тратится на построение суффиксного дерева.

К тому же, IL тоже щтука умная, и true будет возвращено при первом же true - результате в конкатенации по "или".

Отсюда простое соображение: если какая либо из строк в выражении с большей вероятностью попадает в выборку - то есть,содержит подстроку filter - то переместите это сравнение ближе к началу выражения.

А вообще - надо посмотреть на картину целиком,может,там много раз запращивается вычисление одного и того же.

К примеру, если ни одна из строк, в котрых ищется filter, не менялась, и сам фильтр не менялся, то второй раз вычислять не надо. можно вернуть результат предыдущего вычисления.

Но вообще под Вашим вопросом **гораздо более опытный** человек оставил правильное замечение - немного конкретики не помешало бы

К тому же, если я ощибся в своих рассуждениях - я буду благодарен за замечания и исправления.

Comment: Изначально код используется для сортировки табличных элементов, которые ещё и используют ui, так что скорее всего проблема в последующем коде. Спасибо за объяснение, скорее всего тут и в правду всё гладко и надо искать пробел в другом месте, просто хотел поинтересоваться по поводу своего решения с опытными специалистами)

Comment: Ну, гораздо более опытный специалист понял бы, что тут идёт работа со строками, код интуитивно понятен. здесь в принципе везде работа со строками, никаких переводов и т.п. Хотя я с ним соглашусь в этом отношении, но в принципе вы поняли суть, вопрос закрыт, спасибо

Comment: `Contains` работает за примерно  N*M или N (либо то, либо то). Я подозреваю там под капотом что то типа кнута-морриса-пратта. Хранить суффиксные деревья для каждой строки будет сильно расточитально по пямяти.

Comment: Очень сомневаюсь что там и правда суффиксное дерево, это слишком сложный алгоритм для задачи, которая решается алгоритмом КПМ.

Comment: @tym32167 - огромное спасибо, вот именно такие замечания и расширяют кругозор! я по наивности ожидал самый эффективный по времени алгоритм... Автору вопроса надо вернуться к анализу, а мне - исправить и дополнить ответ... Или может кто то свой напишет?

Comment: ну [КМП](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%9A%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B0) он вроде и есть линейный, насколько я помню. То есть это один из самых быстрых алгоритмов среди возможных по поиску подстроки.

Comment: можно [исходники глянуть](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,428c5c9954dea844) но в разных версиях дотнетов алгоритм может быть разный все равно

Comment: @tym32167 лучше заглянуть в свежий дотнет. String.Contains(string) ведет на SpanHelpers.SequenceEqual, а там интересно - https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/331cfe33e187a6234aa2c2447f91793f154bd322/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/SpanHelpers.Byte.cs#L1422

Comment: @aepot, а почему я попал на `kernel32::FindNLSStringEx`?

Comment: @Qwerty к гитхабу вопрос